# How do I pass variables to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, 8

In your MODULENAME.module file:

```php
$testVariable = 'himanshu';
drupal_add_js(array('MODULENAME' => array('testvar' => $testVariable)), array('type' => 'setting'));
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULENAME') . '/MODULENAME.js');
```

In MODULENAME.js file:

```js
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MODULENAME = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      alert(settings.MODULENAME.testvar);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

this way you can pass your php variable in drupal javascript file and use the variable :)

How can I implement the above in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 21):

Instead of `drupal_add_js(array('MODULENAME' => array('testvar' => $testVariable)), array('type' => 'setting'));` you use `$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['testvar'] = $testVariable;`. Replace `$build` with the variable containing the form or the render array to which the settings are attached; in a form builder or `hook_form_alter()`, that would be `$form`.

The JavaScript code to attach to the page should then be defined as library, which is the only way to attach JavaScript and CSS to a page or a form.
It is explained in [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets), so I will not repeat it here. I will just make notice that the library needs to declare at least two dependencies:

- core/jquery, if the JavaScript code uses jQuery
- core/drupalSettings, since the JavaScript code uses Drupal settings

Comment: Just to be precise https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets#configurable-javascript

Comment: @kiamlaluno  I have tried your solution above but it still gives undefined error , can u please look at the code I have added below the updated Answer text in the question

Comment: Ask a new question. You cannot change the meaning of a question once it gets an answer, since it would make the answer invalid.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I have added a new question related to this , please answer to it , thanks http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193212/variable-not-passed-in-javascript-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 5):

For Drupal 8 you can do.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myname'] = 'himanshu';
}

(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  /**
   * @namespace
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleAccessData = {
    attach: function (context) {
      var data = drupalSettings.myname;
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Drupal 8 <sup>(update)</sup>

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function myModule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myModule'] = [
    'basePath' => base_path(),
  ];
}
```

This variable would then be referenced from JS side like:

```js
console.log( drupalSettings.myModule.basePath );
```

Or:

```js
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleAccessData = {
    attach: function (context) {
      var data = drupalSettings.myModule.basePath;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

### Old answer

Another way to do it (as mentiond in [JS-standards](https://www.drupal.org/node/172169)) would be:

```php
$element['#attached']['js'][] = array(
  'data' => array('myModule' => array('basePath' => base_path())), 
  'type' => 'setting',
);
```

This variable would then be referenced from JS side like:

```js
console.log( Drupal.settings.myModule.basePath );
```