# How to call js on file download?

Tags: 8

I have a callback function for downloading images that are called when a link is clicked. So I need to push the image name in a gtm datalayer. But no js is getting called when the file is downloaded. Is there any way to achieve this? Below is example of the flow I'm trying to achieve.

1. Created url in routing.yml

   ```
   test.item.download:
   path: '/test/{item_id}/download'
   defaults:
     _controller:
       '\Drupal\test\Controller\TestController::itemDownload'
   requirements:
     _permission: 'access content'
   ```
2. TestController.php

   ```
   public function itemDownload($item_id) {
     $response = new Response(NULL, 404);
     //download file code
      .... 
     $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file_spl_info, 200, $headers);
     return $response;
   }
   ```
3. Href is given in twig file when the download link is clicked.

Basically, after the return of response, I need to push the file name in the data layer through my js. Is it possible to call js and push the file name in the data layer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables to JavaScript?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193202/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, @Jdrupal. I am aware of this but none of js is getting called when the image download process takes place.

Comment: _Basically, after the return of response_ You won't be able to do that; you can't monitor the success/failure of a file download using javascript

Comment: Thanks @Clive for the response. But is there any other way in drupal that I can use to push the downloaded image name to GTM inside itemDownload() function.

Comment: There isn’t - it’s part of a different request, and can’t update the page it was invoked from unless that page consumes the response (at which point you can’t have it force-downloaded). You’ll have to register the GTM var on click in JS, before allowing the default event to run